# is the R `egg` package part of ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Is the `egg` package part of `ggplot2`? Sometimes I need to explicitly call functions, for example `egg:ggarrange()` and sometime I don't have to explicitly call functions with other `egg` arguments. Do I even need to `install.packages("egg")` if I already have the `tidyverse` installed?

I also find it odd that [the official GitHub page for egg](https://github.com/baptiste/egg) has so few *stars*. Packages this useful typically have hundreds, if not thousands of stars. Egg only has six stars *(ouch)*. I'm in no way affiliated with the package, just curious how it integrates into the `tidyverse`. And it's almost like I'm missing something here. And the package is awesome by the way, but if you're reading this you likely know that.

Comment: No, [`egg` is not part of `tidyverse`](https://github.com/tidyverse?utf8=✓&q=egg). Also, `egg` is not the only one there. `ggpubr` has [`ggarrange`](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr) functionality and [`patchwork`](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) is great too.

Comment: You can look at formal `tidyverse` packages: `grep("egg", tidyverse::tidyverse_packages())`

Comment: to figure out if you have it or not u may run `?egg:ggarrange()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`egg` is not part of the tidyverse, but being an extension package for `ggplot2` it is tightly bound to that package. To use its functions, like any R package, you should either attach it with `library(egg)` or use an explicit namespace directive such as `egg::ggarrange`.

You probably should not attach too much weight to the number of stars given to a github repository — I don't think your claim that useful R packages should have many stars on github is substantiated. If the package is useful to you, use it, download the source, modify it as you please, etc. `egg`'s "official" source code is on CRAN; the github repository could disappear any time.

Comment: I always did wonder what would happen if a package developer decided, "I've had enough" and deleted their package from GitHub... what would happen. It's nice to know it'll still exist forever (exaggeration?) on CRAN. Assuming it's there in the first place.